# ListView Control Error retrieving all groups. Checkboxes are not supported in the Tile View

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a vb.NET Windows Form, where I am using ListView to group Data using ListViewGroups.

Error when trying to display the data using Tile view. "Error retrieving all groups. Checkboxes are not supported in the Tile View. Choose a different view or set Checkboxes to false"

I want to be able to group the data and also be able to use checkbox to make selections. Is there any other control that I could use in this situation. Can we group data if we use the CheckedListBox. Is there any suggestion please assist.

Below is my VB Code.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
            Dim readAccess As New ListViewGroup("Read", HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            Dim writeAccess As New ListViewGroup("Write", HorizontalAlignment.Left)

            clb_ListViewGroups.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("ADMIN", writeAccess))
            clb_ListViewGroups.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("SUPPORT", readAccess))
            clb_ListViewGroups.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("DEVGROUP", writeAccess))
            clb_ListViewGroups.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("MANAGER", readAccess))
            clb_ListViewGroups.Items.Add(New ListViewItem("INTERN", writeAccess))
  
            clb_ListViewGroups.Groups.Add(readAccess)
            clb_ListViewGroups.Groups.Add(writeAccess)

            Controls.Add(clb_ListViewGroups)
            clb_ListViewGroups.View = View.Tile
            clb_ListViewGroups.CheckBoxes = True


Catch eEndEdit As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR RETRIEVING ALL GROUPS:  " + eEndEdit.Message)
        End Try
    
End Sub`
```

Comment: No, not possible to show the check boxes with the `Tile` view. See the [Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) box under the remarks section. Use `View.Details` ?

Comment: The `ListView` is the only standard control that supports grouping out of the box. There may be third-party controls that can do what you want but I suspect that they would not be free. You may be able to jerry-rig something with the `CheckedListBox` if you were to draw the items yourself, although I'm not sure how drawing the checkboxes works. The `DataGridView` may be the best bet, as it is very customisable, but it would be a significant amount of work.